# Необходимо узнать среднее арифметическое массива

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double sum;
        int a;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите длину массива");
        int size = scan.nextInt();//вводим с клавиатуры длину массиваж
        int massiv[] = new int[size]; // создаем массив типа int размера size
        System.out.println("Введите массив");

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            massiv[i] = scan.nextInt();

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print ("Среднее арефмет" + massiv[i]/ size); //ошибка где то здесь,просто делит каждый элемент массива на кол-во элементов


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте просуммировать элементы массива а потом уже делить на размер.

Answer (score 3):

Просто нужно сначала найти сумму всех элементов, а уже потом делить на размер

```
double sum =0;
for(int i =0; i<size; i++){
    sum+= massiv[i];
 }
 System.out.print(sum/size);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
double average = Arrays
                    .stream(array)
                    .summaryStatistics()
                    .getAverage();
System.out.println(average);
```

> 5.5